# A function that creates a Keras model with a customized loss function only work for once

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss-function

I have a contractive autoencoder built using Keras, when I tried to wrap the code in a function, I got some strange errors. The function will work when I run it for the first time, but crash if I run it again.

```
ae, encoder = cae(fm, lam=1e-4) # this works 
ae, encoder = cae(fm, lam=1e-5) # this second call will crash
```

I think it's because of the inner function, but I don't know to fix it.

Here is the code of the function:

```
def cae(feat_mat, hidden_size=800, lam=1e-5, batch_size=128, epochs=2000):

    input_size = feat_mat.shape[1]
    x = Input(shape=(input_size,))
    h = Dense(hidden_size, activation='relu', name='encoded')(x)
    r = Dense(input_size, activation='sigmoid')(h)

    ae= Model(inputs=x, outputs=r)

    def contractive_loss(y_pred, y_true):
        mse = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=1)

        W = K.variable(value=ae.get_layer('encoded').get_weights()[0])  # N x N_hidden
        W = K.transpose(W)  # N_hidden x N
        h = ae.get_layer('encoded').output
        dh = h * (1 - h)  # N_batch x N_hidden

        # N_batch x N_hidden * N_hidden x 1 = N_batch x 1
        contractive = lam * K.sum(dh**2 * K.sum(W**2, axis=1), axis=1)

        return mse + contractive


    ae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=contractive_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = ae.fit(feat_mat, feat_mat, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs, callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor])  
    encoder = Model(x, h)


    return ae, encoder
```

And here is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    278             try:
--> 279                 K.is_keras_tensor(x)
    280             except ValueError:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
    473         raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' +
--> 474                          str(type(x)) + '`. '
    475                          'Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-78d0f91db066> in <module>()
----> 1 cae, c_encoder = cae(data, epochs=20, lam=1e-6)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    438             # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    439             # with the input_spec set at build time.
--> 440             self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    441 
    442             # Handle mask propagation.

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    283                                  'Received type: ' +
    284                                  str(type(x)) + '. Full input: ' +
--> 285                                  str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
    286                                  'should be tensors.')
    287 

ValueError: Layer model_5 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. Full input: [array([[0.        , 0.00408104, 0.00367454, ..., 0.47897612, 0.37681195,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.03629775, ..., 0.06981143, 0.07543451,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.09040481, 0.09040481,
        0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.09401818, 0.09401818,
        0.11997618],
       [0.        , 0.11205364, 0.        , ..., 0.05691057, 0.05691057,
        0.07582368],
       [0.1818507 , 0.20749162, 0.18682415, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]])]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

A workaround would be to have the code as a script instead of inside a function, but I really would like to wrap it and also wonder the solution to the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your traceback is complete? It does not start in your code.

Comment: Yes, that's the complete traceback. The start is in the middle `----> 1 cae, c_encoder = cae(data, epochs=20, lam=1e-6)` @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: The exception in your code is a nested exception, that's why I say its confusing. Are you sure you did not overwrite the cae function with a variable (also called cae)? Because that is what it would look like if you did.

Comment: You're assigning the return of your `cae` function to a variable called `cae` in the line `cae, c_encoder = cae(data, epochs=20, lam=1e-6)` from your traceback. I imagine this is going to cause some issues the second time you try to call it. Call your returned variable something else and see if that helps.

Comment: @Engineero, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your exception this is the function call you are making:

```
 cae, c_encoder = cae(data, epochs=20, lam=1e-6)
```

Here you have a function called `cae`, and a variable also named `cae`, which overwrites the original function. Never name variables the same as a function, as it will produce this kind of weird errors.

Solution? Rename the variable or the function.

Comment: Thank you! I always thought it was a keras problem. Never suspect it would be a python mis-use.